# Convert integer to a date string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime, integer

In Objective-C:  Is there a **simple** way, as in Excel and SAS, to convert an integer into a datetime string?

In Excel, you'd format to "mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss".

For instance, if I had the integer:
1328062560

and I want the output to be:
2012-01-31 21:16:00

or even (as in Excel):
Jan 31, 2012 21:16:00

PS: I don't want to be too demanding, but I'd like it **simple** and **inline** *for use in NSLog*, so I can write simply for debugging 
NSLog("The time as an integer is %d and as a date %mmmddyyyyhh:mm:ss", [array objectAtIndex: i], [array objectAtIndex: i]);

Answer (score 12):

You can get an `NSDate` object like this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1328062560];
```

Then, if you don't care about the exact format of the string, you can just do this:

```
NSString *s = [date description];
```

That will give you a string like “`2012-02-01 02:16:00 +0000`”.

If you want a specific string format, use an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: This worked fine for me, although I'm not using it with NSLog. Thanks!

Comment: how to change the format of this date and how to remove +0000?? please help

Comment: “If you want a specific string format, use an `NSDateFormatter`.”

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` to do this. You first make a string from your integer value:

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", integerDate];
```

And then create an `NSDateFormatter` with the corresponding format:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmm"]; // Change to suit your format
NSDate *dateFromString = [myDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

You can then retrieve the date as a string in the format you want:

```
[myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm"]; // Change to suit your format
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

Comment: By the way: I'd like to do it "inline" for NSLog, and **not** have to have 3 or 4 lines of alloc and init, and create a string, and then a NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @user945869, welcome to the "Apple way" I guess. :p And since they control the publishing channels, developers can't choose an alternate language or framework with the features they like. Get out while you can. ;) I #define a macro to do my logging and I can add whatever code I want there, and undefine it instead of removing all the log lines for the final version.

Comment: Henrik:  thanks for your humorous approach.  I'm getting in deeper, but I thought there would be a quick-and-dirty way to format a time; e.g.    stringDate = put(timeIntervalSince1970, ddmmmyyyy.);  as might be done in SAS.  Peter aka user945869

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that integer is a time in seconds since the epoch, you can use `NSDate`'s `initWithTimeIntervalSince1970` or `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` methods to create an `NSDate` object with the date you care about, and then use `NSDateFormatter` to pretty it up for display.